# installing python-xml packages

Tags: apt, package-management, python-2.7

I want to install `python-xml` package on ubuntu. 
I see this command for installing it:

`sudo apt-get install python-xml`

but

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-xmlReading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python-xml
```

Should I add repository to fix it?

Comment: The package you need, PyXML is dead http://georgik.sinusgear.com/2011/01/10/dead-project-warning-pyxml-does-not-work-with-python2-6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `python-xml` package in the repository. What made you decide you need a package with that specific name? Are you looking for `python-lxml` instead? This is the common Python XML library that I believe most people use.

Comment: I want to install a package that need `python-xml`. How i can install it?

Comment: Since `python-xml` doesn't exist, either your package needs something from a non-official repository, or your package is in error by requiring it, or you're mistaken about the package name. To help others figure out what's going on, can you edit your question with more information on the wider problem that you're actually trying to solve? Otherwise you might as well be asking "how do I do this impossible thing that cannot be done"?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to install the pyhrf project which depends of PyXML, but PyXML is dead, and wont work on Python 2.6 or newer. I would recommend to look for another project similar to pyhrf.

Comment: I think `PyXML` python package have been installed by `python-xml` but `python-lxml' doesnt install it

Comment: @28 exactly what don't install? What module exactly?

Comment: I want to install `pyhrf` package

Comment: @28 what have pyhrf to do with xml?